# Power BI - Pie Chart

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have several measures in Power BI.

```
[A],
[B],
[C],
[D],
[Total Expenses]
```

Where `A + B + C + D = Total Expenses`. For this example, let's say the first 4 measures = 25 and the Total Expenses measure = 100

I want to create a Pie Chart that will show me the allocation of selected Expenses compared to the total. In other words, if I select `A`, `B`, and `D` (in a filter for example). Then I want the Pie Chart to show me `A` = 25%, `B` = 25%, `C` = 25%, `Other` = 25%. If I remove `A`, then `Other` should become 50%.

I was thinking this might be possible with something like the `SWITCH` function... but can't really imagine how to start. I will also accept alternative functions I haven't heard of that might lead to the desired solution...

Comment: This is a bit of an odd request. Measures don't typically go in slicers/filters and pie charts don't typically operate on multiple measures (you put one measure in the Values section).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are after, but this might prove instructive.

If I set up a table like this:

[image: Table]

And a measure like this:

```
Other = IF(SELECTEDVALUE(Pie[Type]) <> "Other",
        SUM(Pie[Amount]),
        CALCULATE(SUM(Pie[Amount]), ALL(Pie[Type])) - CALCULATE(SUM(Pie[Amount]), ALLSELECTED(Pie[Type])))
```

Then I can get a pie chart that behaves like you describe (where `Type` goes in the Legend field and the `[Other]` measure goes in the Values field.

[image: Pie Chart]